# Share view model with 3 views

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin to build an application that runs on iPad (and now, it must run in iPhone).

I've got a view that was design for iPad, it has a table on the left (to select an object), a view with a background image and paths drawn over it (represent the selected object) in the center, and a table on the right with a search box to filter objects that are being represented by the paths.

Something like:

A  B  C
[-][--][-]

When you select something in A (left table), A will disappear and B will be the main view (image). C only appears if you click on a button that exists somewhere in the image. Anything you write on C search box will affect the paths drawn in B (change the path background color).

This works perfectly well with an iPad, there is room for everything, if the right search area is visible, the image is shifted to the right, if one wants to select another item in A, then the image is shifted to the left until you select the new item.

Now, my "client" wants this to work on an iPhone and Android and since I began this project using mvvmcross and Xamarin (guessing that, eventually the client would like to see this in another format and devices - but I didn't planned this screen very well for small formats).

Due to screen restrictions on an iPhone it seems that I can only show A, B or C view at each time.

My question is, is there a way to do something similar (or use an existing control) like the settings control in ios (one control that has different behaviours in iPhone or iPad) that enables me to do have one or more views visible depending on the device format?

Sorry for the long post and thank you for your support,

L. Pinho

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n24-splitviewpresenter-n1-days-of.html - looks like this is what you are looking for.
Thanks